# Hot to get website/product reviews reflected in Google's search results using review-aggregate format

Tags: rich-snippets, microformats

I am managing a website called [Rent A Boat Amsterdam](http://www.rentaboatamsterdam.com). We have a system that gathers reviews from people that have used our services and that publishes these customer reviews making them available for all website visitors.

When these customer reviews are published we have placed them within the appropriate tags according to the [guidelines set by Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=146645).

An example looks like this:

```html
<li class="" style="clear:both;"> 
<div class="hreview"> 
    <div class="item" style="display:none;"><span class="fn">Boatname</span></div> 
    <div style="border:1px solid #DEDEDE; background-color:#D9FFD4; margin:0 10px 10px 0; float:left; text-align:center; padding:10px; height:50px; width:70px;"><h1><span class="rating">10</span></h1>9-Jun-2010</div>                    
<div> 
<div class="description"><p>Great canal Cruise!</p></div> 
<p class="reviewer vcard"><strong><span class="fn">First name Last name</span></strong></p> 
</div> 
</div>
```

We have implemented these tags a couple of months ago, but there are no visible results in the Google SERPs. This whilst I had expected to find the reviews/ratings displayed similar to:

> [image: Google example of enhanced snippet]

Is anyone familiar with this topic and able to help me find the answer to the question why the review-aggregate format doesn't seem to have the desired effect?

Comment: I have found a tool via http://www.goboozo.com/2011/03/microformatting-rich-snippets/ that lets you test your Markup: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 2):

You need sufficient competition offering semantically extractable reviews on-line otherwise Google has nothing to compare your offerings with and won't display them. Try to get customers of your competitors to fill in local business reviews (especially if they had a bad time) this will help.

Remember that this is made all the more difficult as you are offering a service instead of a product (this can be got around with offering "tickets" or similar for one-day, one-week, etc hire).

Otherwise try your luck with their ["I'm using Rich Snippets on my site" form](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/request.py?contact_type=rich_snippets_feedback), although don't hold your breath, no-one I know that has used it had any joy.

**EDIT:**

From the [Google Knol entry on Rich Snippets](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#):

> Currently, review sites and social
>   networking/people profile sites are
>   eligible. We plan to expand Rich
>   Snippets to other types of content in
>   the future.

As per the advice on local business reviews (above) - get your reviews on a "review site" for now and watch out for those [being penalised by Google's Panda](http://rview.reviewcentre.com/the-panda-in-the-room/) algorithm updates.

The [Knol article](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#) also mentions:

> Google does not guarantee that Rich
>   Snippets will show up for search
>   results from a particular site even if
>   structured data is marked up and can
>   be extracted successfully according to
>   the testing tool. Here are some
>   reasons that marked-up pages might not
>   be shown with Rich Snippets:
>
> - The marked-up structured data is not
>     representative of the main content of
>     the page.
> - Marked-up data is incorrect
>     or misleading.
> - Marked up content is
>     hidden from the user (see the section
>     above: "Hidden div's -- don't do it!")
> - The site has very few pages (or very
>     few pages with marked-up structured
>     data) and may not be picked up by
>     Google's Rich Snippets system.